# MIME 1.0 URL contains %0D%20

Tags: php, mime-types, mime

I have a PHP script which emails a user upon submission, but I've run into an issue where the embedded link in the message contains %0D%20 within the URL itself.

I cannot figure out how to get rid of this as when you click on the link, this is obviously not the link.

The displayed URL is correct, without the %0D%20, however, it's when you hover over the  tag that I see this information.

When you click on the link it opens as:

```
https://URL/public/dermatology/2019/client_generatePDF.p%0D hp?id=21%08 8&pid=Horus
```

Where there's now a %0D in the middle of the extension php and a %08 in the middle of the database ID which is from the $last_id that is, the ID of the record inserted into the database

I've also tried href='" . $url_pdf ."'

This is the Link portion of the script.

```
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Link to full history: <a href='$url_pdf' target='_blank'>" . $url_pdf ." </a></td></tr>";




$last_id = $stmt->insert_id;
    $PetName2 = trim($_POST['Pet_Name']);

    $url = "https://URL/public/dermatology/2019/client_upload_form.php?id=". $last_id . "&pid=" . $PetName2 ;
    $url_pdf = "https://URL/public/dermatology/2019/client_generatePDF.php?id=". $last_id . "&pid=" . $PetName2 ;

    $email = "SEND EMAIL";
    $to = "EMAIL, $ClientEmailAddress";
    $from = "VMC Dermatology Form Submission";
    $subject = "Dermatology Client Form Submission: " . $UMNCaseNo . "";

    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";

    $message = '<html><body><h3>A Dermatology Consultation Has Been Submitted.</h3><br />';
    $message .= "<br />";
    $message .= "<br />";
    $message .= "Thank you&nbsp; " . $Client_First_Name ." &nbsp; for filling out the Dermatology Questionnaire for your pet " .$Pet_Name . ".&nbsp;Your information has been received. If applicable, you may submit photos regarding your pets skin condition using the following link. <a href='" .$url. "' > ". $url ."</a>";
    $message .= "<br />";
    $message .= "<br />";
    $message .= "<table rules='all' style='border-color: #666;' cellpadding='10'>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'>  <td width='178px'><strong>Today's Date:</strong> </td>  
                  <td width='380px'>" . $date2 . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr> <td><strong>Case Number:</strong></td>  <td>" . $UMNCaseNo . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr> <td><strong>Clinic to Be Seen at:</strong></td>  <td>" . $ClinicToBeSeenAt . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr> <td><strong>Client Name:</strong> </td><td>" . $Client_First_Name . " ". $Client_Last_Name ."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Client Phone Number:</strong></td> <td>" . $Phone . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Client Email:</strong></td> <td>" . $ClientEmailAddress . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Pet Name:</strong></td> <td>" . $Pet_Name . "</td></tr>";  
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Species:</strong></td> <td>" . $Species . "</td></tr>";    
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Breed:</strong></td> <td>" . $Breed . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee'><td colspan='2'><strong>Reason for Visit:</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $Reason_for_Visit . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Link to full history: <a href='$url_pdf' target='_blank'>" . $url_pdf ." </a></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $message .= "<br />";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
```

Answer (score 0):

`%0D%20` is a URL-encoded line break followed by a space. Browsers will display the decoded version of that, which is why you only see it on rollover. Filter your filenames for characters like that, for example with:

```
$url_pdf = preg_replace('/[ \n\r\t]/', '', $url_pdf);
```

You will of course need to make sure your files are saved using this filtered name, otherwise your downloads will break.

I'd also recommend using PHPMailer, since you tagged the question with it.

Comment: Thanks. That does not work. I did not include it above and I should have, these characters are being included in the name of a "static" document on the server.  So the hoverable URL that displays is something like 
https://URL/public/dermatology/2019/client_generatePDF.p%0D hp?id=21%08 8&pid=Horus

where the document on the server is called    client_generatedPDF.php and then it's throwing an %08 in the middle of a the database ID which is the $last_id

Comment: Looks like you need to do more filtering on input; those characters should not be getting in there in the first place.

Comment: There is NO input for that information. It is a set URL. The link is set. the only thing I'm including is the number, which comes from the database. It's not any data that is inputted anywhere by anyone other than the database.

Comment: The set URL that is hardcoded is client_generatePDF.php?id=$last_id&pid=$Pet_Name (the $Pet_Name is the only data that is inputted in an html form. but this is not the issue... The issue is the actual hard coded URL and the $last_id, which is being inserted into the URL string from the database.

Comment: It's getting in there somehow. Validate everything. Assume nothing. Don't trust what you can see either - hex dump your strings and check every byte.